# How do you style HTML inside PHP using CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

I need to be able to style some simple HTML I've written in PHP

**PHP:**

```
if ($result-> num_rows> 0) {
  readfile("ViewReturn.html");
  while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Bird Name: ".$row["pageLink"]. "<br><br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

I would like to be able to style the HTML I'm outputting at "birdname" and "page link" because it doesn't sit very well on the page. Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

Comment: Same way as you'd style any html. Give it some class, id, whatever and style it

Comment: At some point you can probably look into templating. It can save you lots of grief as your application grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the bird name in a `<span>` with a `class` and style the class using CSS.

Do it as below

```
 echo "<span class='birdname'>Bird Name: ".$row["pageLink"]. "</span><br><br>";
```

ie, replace your code as

```
if ($result-> num_rows> 0) {
  readfile("ViewReturn.html");
  while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<span class='birdname'>Bird Name: ".$row["pageLink"]. "</span><br><br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

and in CSS, add

```
.birdname{
   color:red;
}
```

Comment: `class="birdname"` will cause a server error. Change to single quotes

Comment: ...or escape it with `\"`

Comment: oops..sorry..my mistake..thanks for pointing out @MarcosPérezGude ..updated the answer..

Comment: Thanks for that valid suggestion @Qirel

Comment: you can variate de quotes.. echo '<html tag="asdasd">'.$varphp.'</html>';

Comment: You forgot to update the quotes around `class="birdname"` in the second block of code

Comment: Again a mistake...oh ho.. :D..sorry..fixed it..thanks.. @MattD.

Comment: echo '<span class="birdname">Bird Name: '.$row['pageLink']. '</span><br /><br />';

Comment: Yes..got it..Thankyou..:) @fabiovaz

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your `echo` command the `html elements` just as you were writing directly on **HTML** file. For example:

```
echo "<div class='some-class'>"
while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<someTag class='other-class' >". "Bird Name: ".$row["pageLink"]. "<br><br>" . "</someTag>";
}
echo "</div>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can style your result by adding these elements
Like

```
 echo "<p class='birdy'>Bird Name: " . $row["pageLink"] . "</p >";
```

then in your CSS file or inline or in STYLE

```
.birdy{
   color:blue;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: The same problem. Your double quotes will produce a server error.

Comment: use single qoutes then

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
     if ($result-> num_rows> 0) {
        readfile("ViewReturn.html");
        while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
?>
        <span class="birdname">Bird Name: <?php echo $row['pageLink']; ?> </span>
        <br><br>
<?php
        }
      } else {
         echo "0 results";
     }  
?>
```